# how to create a new iframe with specify charset in firefox?

Tags: firefox, iframe, utf-8

firefox

paraent page ：charset is utf8

now want to create a iframe page ：charset is gbk

but firefox seem can't set characterSet

```
var doc = window.content.document;
var iframe=doc.createElement("iframe");  
iframe.src="about:blank";  
iframe.setAttribute("style","display:none;visibility:hidden;");  
doc.body.appendChild(iframe);  

var d; 

if(iframe.contentDocument) { 
        d = iframe.contentDocument; 
} else {
        d = iframe.contentWindow.document; 
}
d.charset=d.characterSet="GBK";  
d.documentElement.innerHTML="<body><span>some GBK</span></body>";
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

... "IE has scriptable `document.charset` property which is officially read/
write.

Gecko-based browsers do have read-only `document.characterSet` property." ...

**Reference:**
http://forums.asp.net/t/1772657.aspx/1

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't matter what the Iframe's encoding is since there is no decoding happening when you directly set iframe contents to some string. If there is a problem, then the *javascript file* that contains

```
d.documentElement.innerHTML="<body><span>some GBK</span></body>";
```

has been encoded incorrectly or declared in the wrong encoding.

Comment: yes, the span "some GBK" content is extract from parent utf8 page. I want to covert it to gbk encoding.

Comment: @abbypan there is no encoding concerned at that point, what is the real problem here?

Comment: thanks a lot. the problem is : select a text frome a utf8 encoding page, post form to a gbk page. my solution is add a form in page, and  form.setAttribute('accept-charset', 'gbk'); then it's ok.